# Swift3 | Spritekit | Two different NSIntegers with the same userdefaults key is returning wrong saved value

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, nsinteger

Can anyone explain the following to this please and have a alternative?
I've just put a simple example as my code is pretty large.

```
//Declare too variables
var levelStars = NSInteger()        
var levelScore = NSInteger()

//Load the variables
levelStars = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "1")
levelScore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "1")

//Set the variables
levelStars = 3
levelScore = 1000

//Save the variables
UserDefaults.standard.set(levelStars, forKey: "1")
UserDefaults.standard.set(levelScore, forKey: "1")            

//Now when I call the following variable for levelStars
levelStars = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "1")
print(levelStars)    OUPUT: 1000  should be 3
```

The value returned is 1000 when it should be 3 for levelstars. 
I assume its because I used the same key and its just overwriting any previous userdefault with the same key value. However I do not understand why...
The values have been set to different NSIntegers.

Comment: It seems as if you overwrite the _value_ associated with the _key_ `"1"` in the `UserDefaults`. You first write value `3` for key `"1"`, thereafter overwrite the value with value `1000`. When you get the value for key `"1"`, the latter is returned. Note that the first argument to `UserDefault.standard.set(_ value, forKey ...)` is of type `Int`, which is a value type, so the first argument is passed as a copy.

Comment: okay, figured that might be happening, so am i right in saying userdefaults are not unique to the nsintegers variables? and the keys should not be reused in any instance?

Comment: From the description of the parameters to the `...set(...)`, it is quite clear that such is the case: _`value`: The integer value to store in the defaults database., `defaultName`: The key with which to associate with the value._ -- in no way does the `UserDefault.standard.set` set up a separate dictionary for each variable you use to provide the `value` as argument to the `set(_:forKey)` method: the _keys_ (`forKey` ext. name, `defaultName` internal name) are used to differentiate between different properties whose values you want to persist using `UserDefaults`.

Comment: ... See [the reference for `UserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults) for additional details; specifically the ref. for the [`set(_:,forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1413614-set) method.

Comment: ahh :( going to be a big pain now to change the existing code now. I guess I will need to create dictionaries now for each variable.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that you needn't add single value-by-value to userdefaults in case you have more "complex" data. E.g. for your stars and score example (where I assume that the `forKey` corresponds to level) you could e.g. add a dictionary (`[String:[String:Int])` to the userdefaults, where the key of the outer dictionary corresponds to level (e.g. `"1"`), and where the value is another dictionary which itself holds values for a number of keys (in your case, the inner dict for outer dict `key = "1"` would look something like `["level": 3, "score": 1000]`).

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need a dictionary. I think you need an example to understand it:

```
//Declare too variables
…

//Load the variables
levelStars = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "com.yourcomp.yourapp.levelStars")
levelScore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "com.yourcomp.yourapp.levelScore")

//Set the variables
…

//Save the variables
UserDefaults.standard.set(levelStars, forKey: "com.yourcomp.yourapp.levelStars")
UserDefaults.standard.set(levelScore, forKey: "com.yourcomp.yourapp.levelScore")            

//Now when I call the following variable for levelStars
levelStars = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "com.yourcomp.yourapp.levelStars")
print(levelStars)
```